# What does runtime mean in the context of the .NET CLR?

Tags: .net, clr, runtime

What does **"Runtime"** mean in the context of the .NET Common Language **Runtime**?

Comment: Not great, but close enough: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime in that context is an execution platform. I.e. it defines how applications are loaded and executed. It provides a set of services common to all applications on the platform, e.g. memory management and just-in-time compilation of intermediate code.

Comment: Does the CLR act like Java's Virtual Machine type platform?

Answer (score 0):

It's a pointless abbreviation for 'runtime system', which nowadays appears to mean an interpreter, although it didn't start out that way. When I first encountered the term, it just meant a shared runtime library, that might or might not include an interpreter.

Comment: What makes you say that the .NET runtime is an interpreter? IL is JIT compiled and executed as native code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice explaining picture:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime

You write the code in different languages, it's compiled to CIL (Intermediate Language). Then CLR converts Intermediate Language into Native Code. And it happens at **runtime**.